# Generating 'random' numbers from time?

Tags: c++, c, random, time

I have read about many random number generators and all problems that most have (repeatable, non-uniform distribution, floating-point precision, modulus w/e).

I'm a game developer and I'm thinking why not generate 'random' numbers from time ? I know they won't be 'random', but at least they can't be predicted and I'm only happy for them to just feel random for the players.

For example let's say, at every frame we can take 5 digits out of the current time and use them to generate random numbers.
Let's say if we have the time as a float **ss.mmmuuunnn** where **ss** = seconds, **mmm** = miliseconds, **uuu** = microseconds and **nnn** = nanoseconds, we can take only the part **muuun** and use this to generate our very own random numbers. I have investigated them a bit, and they seem and feel pretty random. I can come up with so many formulas to play around with those 5 digits and get new numbers.

Anyone here seeing anything wrong or that can perform miserably ?
Reminder, I'm just looking for an easy way to generate numbers that 'FEEL' randomly distributed and are unpredictable.

Is this an easy and decent way to give players the sense of randomness ?

Comment: If you want extremely fast, not-too-obviously-predictable, numbers, you could try the [DOOM approach](https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM/blob/master/linuxdoom-1.10/m_random.c). And honestly, how fast is a system call to lookup the current time anyway? Using some sort of PRNG **seeded** from the time but keeping state in your own memory is probably much faster. A [linear congruential generator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/linear_congruential_engine) has poor "randomness", but little state and is very fast.

Comment: I am not convinced there's a problem here that wouldn't be solved by an out-of-the-box pseudo-random number generator.

Comment: My method with time is also extremly fast, I already have the time every frame (it is required anyway)... so I will only do a couple more simple operations on it. I will take a look on the DOOM approach though, haven't heard of it yet, thank you :)

Comment: You have same modulus problem BTW. What's wrong with regular PRNG ?

Comment: @AlinIonutLipan Bear in mind, doing things a non-idiomatic way just because it might be *slightly* better, when there is no real problem to solve, makes your code significantly harder to understand.

Comment: if you are fine with "low" quality randomness you could even use `rand()`. If however, you want to get the first 1000 digits of pi via monte carlo then you wont get far with `rand()`

Comment: Funnily enough, actually random numbers (or anything that comes at least somewhat close) often don't feel particularly random because, for example, the probability of repetition feels "too high".

Comment: srand(time(NULL)) is boilerplate, Google has 310,000 hits for it :)

Comment: Is this a duplicate?

Comment: Why you can't use boost? You can use UUID.

Comment: It's not that I want to do things non-idiomatic... if I can use as few libraries as possible that would be really great... and srand is known to have problems and should be considered deprecated. I tried to implement a pseudo random number generator and I was not happy with the results. My only question was with time... because it feels so simple... and if it's simple why not ? I just wanted to know if anyone sees any problem with the time method.
PS: i watched this also
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: "I have investigated them a bit, and they seem and feel pretty random." LOL. Use them in srand(), what the problem?

Comment: @AlinIonutLipan "if I can use as few libraries as possible..." - I can understand not wanting to introduce extra dependencies, but why avoid things that are in the Standard Library? (except the deprecated bits, I understand)

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, this time thing works just fine for me... I just don't want to have unexpected surprises later on :D That's why I asked your opinion on this time approach.

Comment: The problem in using low bytes from a high precision time is that you cannot be sure of the actual *random*. Time function is good at giving time *at an acceptable precision for the system*. It never guarantees a good entropy on its lowest bits. That precisely the reason why (pseudo-)random generators were invented. What is the problem in using `rand` or `random` from C or one from the various generators from the C++ `<random>` module? `rand` and `srand` do have know problems, but your algorithm is probably just a little worse...

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume for the sake of the argument that you are making, on average, one call to your random function every 0.1 milliseconds (since you need it to be fast, you are calling it often, right?) and that it is equally probable to fall anywhere into that time range. In other words, the **uun** part is assumed to be completely random, but everything higher only changes slowly from call to call and is thus mostly predictable.

That is 1000 possible outcomes or ~10 bits of randomness. There are [1,056,964,608 normal floats bewteen 0 and 1](https://lemire.me/blog/2017/02/28/how-many-floating-point-numbers-are-in-the-interval-01/) - not equally distributed of course. That's three orders of magnitude more, which sounds like "poor randomness" to me. Similarly, spreading your 10 bits to the 32 bits of an `int` (no matter how fancy your function) won't actually improve the randomness.

Also note that none of this deals with the possibility (and very likely scenario) that your calls will probably be extremely periodic and/or in short sequences, as well as the fact that your system time function might not have high enough resolution (or [significantly increase power consumption of the system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/high-resolution-timers)). Both further reducing the randomness of the obtained time, and the side effect of the latter can be very undesirable.

> Reminder, I'm just looking for an easy way to generate numbers that 'FEEL' randomly distributed and are unpredictable.

That is extremely unspecific. Humans are terrible at judging randomness and will likely "feel" a close-to-uniform distribution to be more random than a true, fully random one - especially when it comes to streaks.

Unpredictability also exists on way too many levels, from "the player can't manually predict what the enemy will do" to "cryptographically secure until the end of time". For example, given the above assumptions, it might be possible to predict the result of the second of two random calls that happen in quick succession with a success rate of anywhere from 0.1% to 100%. How this pattern emerges in a game is hard to tell, but humans are exceedingly good at spotting patterns.

Comment: "but humans are exceedingly good at spotting patterns." -- Even when they are not there.